# Can't seem to get javascript code working from child theme

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

my javascript code isn't working. I put the js folder next to the other folders, the astra-child folder, astra folder and other themes. Is this correct. Then in the js folder, I created custom_script.js file and put the javascript in there. And in functions.php file enqueued it.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Astra Child Theme functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package Astra Child
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

/**
 * Define Constants
 */
define( 'CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

/**
 * Enqueue styles
 */
function child_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'astra-child-theme-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('astra-theme-css'), CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION, 'all' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );

}

function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
'custom-script',
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
);
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');

}
```

Comment: The problem is that your `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');` is inside the function `my_scripts_method`, move it out of the function and it should work. You also seem to have a floating `}` under `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );` for no reason, remove it.

Comment: I have taken the floating } out. What do you mean, that the add action is inside the function. I got this online, how to do it. Do you mean, I must put it on top before the function as follows: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method', ); wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, you have a few problems with this code.

1. closing bracket `}` for no reason.
2. a extra `,` in the `wp_enqueue_script` at the end
3. `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');` is inside `my_scripts_method` function

This is your current code with some formating and comments to show the problematic code sections.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Astra Child Theme functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package Astra Child
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

/**
 * Define Constants
 */
define( 'CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

/**
 * Enqueue styles
 */
function child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'astra-child-theme-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('astra-theme-css'), CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION, 'all' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );

// this closing bracket is not needed
}

function my_scripts_method() {
    // this functions contains , at the end, not needed
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',);
    // this add_action cannot be inside its own  the callback function
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
}
```

This is the corrected code.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Astra Child Theme functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package Astra Child
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

/**
 * Define Constants
 */
define( 'CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

/**
 * Enqueue styles
 */
function child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'astra-child-theme-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('astra-theme-css'), CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION, 'all' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );

function my_scripts_method() {
    // this functions contains , at the end, not needed
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried all that, still doesn't show anything. Could you please explain the add_action part. As the corrected code seems to look the same in that part. What must I change in add_action.

Comment: @SpencerHalstead Have you tried checking the devtools? under network you can see what files are being requested. That can give you a better understanding about what are the paths that being requested.

Comment: There is nothing there in networks. only says Recording network activity, perform a request or hit ctrl+r to record the reload. I am using local by flyweel on my computer with wordpress, but also haven't been able to get any code to work on my live site either.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create `function my_scripts_method()` just call your script from `child_enqueue_styles()` function, like you did with your style.css file, but using `wp_enqueue_script`. As you can see from `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );` it's for both - scripts and styles.

**Tested & working example:**

```
 /**
  * Define Constants
  */
 define( 'CHILD_THEME_TORRCH_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

 /**
  * Enqueue styles & scripts
  */
 function child_enqueue_styles() {

     wp_enqueue_style( 'astra-child-theme-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'style.css', array('astra-theme-css'), CHILD_THEME_TORRCH_VERSION, 'all' );

     wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', array(), CHILD_THEME_TORRCH_VERSION, true );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );
```